# Генератор вещественных чисел C++

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь выполнить задание:

**Создать вещественный массив и преобразовать его таким образом, чтобы в первой его половине располагались элементы, модуль которых не превышает 1, потом все остальные.**

Никак не могу сгенерировать значения - получаются либо меньше единицы, либо больше. Дошло до того, что начал делать "примитивно", как в коде ниже, без подобных конструкций:
   `(double)(rand()) / RAND_MAX * (max - min) + min` 
Проблема в том, что массив заполняется теперь 0 или 1, не знаю, что делать с заданием.
Прошу вашей помощи.
Код ниже:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
int N;
cout << "Enter matrix size: ";
cin >> N;

double *A = new double[N];
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int A2  =  rand() % 100 -50;
    if (A2 / 2 == 0) {
        A[i] = 1.0 + (double)(A2 / 100);
    }
    else {
        A[i] = (double)(A2 / 100);
    }
    cout << setw(2) << A[i];
}
cout << endl;
system("pause");



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Раз упоминается модуль - значит, числа могут быть и отрицательными. Пример: `A[i] = 4.0 * rand() / RAND_MAX - 2.0;`

Comment: Раз уж метка `c++`, то используйте `<random>`. У `rand()` результаты хуже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно создавать массив в куче, если потом не удаляете, условие поставлено не верное для инициализации отрезков массива и нужно убрать скобочки вокруг  `A2 / 100` иначе это  целочисленный тип, значение которого равно нулю, так как `А2 < 100`, а после этого вы преобразуете в тип `double`...

```
int N;
cout << "Enter matrix size: ";
cin >> N;    
double A[N];
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int A2  =  rand() % 100 -50;
    if (i >= N / 2) {
        A[i] = 1.0 + (double)A2 / 100;
    }
    else {
        A[i] = (double)A2 / 100;
    }
    cout << setw(8) << A[i];
}
cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Для ваших целей будет достаточно

```
rand()*a/RAND_MAX
```

где `a` - число типа **`double`**, равное там 2 или 3 - словом, чтоб генерировались числа от 0 до `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Если числа от `double a` до `double b`, то

```
rand()*(b-a)/RAND_MAX+a
```

Ваша проблема в том, что вы неверно применяетте

```
(double)(A2 / 100)
```

так что превращаете в `double` результат целочисленного деления, а надо

```
double(A2) / 100
```

или того проще -

```
A2 / 100.
```